# Change the order of integration of the following double integral

Tags: integration

$$\int\limits_{\frac{\pi}{2}}^{\frac{5\pi}{2}}  \int\limits_1^{\sin x} f(x,y) dy dx$$

I sketched the region and noticed that if I somehow shift the region by $2\pi$ to the left then I can use the $\arcsin $ function. However the correct answer was $$\int\limits_{-1}^{1}  \int\limits_{\pi - \arcsin y}^{\arcsin y + 2\pi} f(x,y) dx dy$$  How can this be found?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have the limits of $x : \frac{\pi}{2}$ to $\frac{5\pi}{2}$
and the limits of $y: 1$ to $\sin x$

We need to convert these such that $y$ lies between $2$ constant limits and $x$ has limits which involve $x$ as a function of $y$.

Now, from $x = \frac{\pi}{2}$ to $\frac{5\pi}{2}$, the highest value $y$ can achieve is $\boxed{1}$ and the lowest value is $\sin\frac{3\pi}{2} = \boxed{-1}$  (you can observe this from the graph)

[image]

If $y = \sin x$, then $x = \arcsin(y)$. But, $\arcsin$ has a principal range $[-\frac\pi2,\frac\pi2]$ So we must do transformations accordingly (to bring the term in the required range)

First let us consider the branch for which $\frac\pi2\le x\le\frac{3\pi}2 $  (length $=\pi$)

$\frac\pi2\le x\le\frac{3\pi}2 \Rightarrow -\frac{\pi}{2} \le x - \pi\le \frac\pi2$ or $ -\frac{\pi}{2} \le  \pi-x \le \frac\pi2$
So $\pi-x$ lies in our required range.

Now, $y= \sin(x) = \sin(\pi-x) \Rightarrow\pi-x = \arcsin(y) \Rightarrow \boxed{ x = \pi-\arcsin(y)}$

Again consider $\frac{3\pi}2\le x\le\frac{5\pi}2 $  (length $=\pi$)

$\frac{3\pi}2\le x\le\frac{5\pi}2 \Rightarrow -\frac{\pi}{2} \le x - 2\pi\le \frac\pi2$
So $x-2\pi$ lies in our required range.

Now, $y = \sin(x) = -\sin(2\pi-x) = \sin(x-2\pi) \Rightarrow \boxed{x =2\pi+\arcsin(y)} $

[image]

Finally subbing the limits:

> The integral becomes $\begin{align}\int_{y=-1}^{1}\int_{x= \pi-arcsin(y)}^{2\pi+\arcsin(y)} f(x,y)dxdy\end{align}$